# Join table to get column along with group by clause in prisma query

Tags: sql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Looking for Prisma query for join with the group by.

What will be the Prisma query for the below SQL?

```sql
select ps.platform_id, count(1) as count, pl.name 
from posts ps join platforms pl on ps.platform_id = pl.id 
group by ps.platform_id, pl.name;
```

Tables `posts` and `platforms` have many-2-many relationship using the 3rd table named `post_platforms` having `post_id` and `platform_id` as foreign keys.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined your schema file? What kind of relation exists between Post and Platform?

Comment: Tables posts and platforms have many-2-many relationship using the 3rd table named post_platforms having post_id and platform_id as foreign keys.
(Edited the question)